# Compiling upstream kernel with my own .config file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to compile upstream kernel with my own .config file.

I copied this file to the root directory.

I run 'make oldconfig' but seems that no consideration on that file because the compiler ask me questions about the configuration and I want that all the configuration will take from the my .config file:

"Compile also drivers which will not load (COMPILE_TEST) [N/y/?] (NEW)"

Answer (score 0):

The makefile (not compiler) is asking you those questions, because following options (as CONFIG_COMPILE_TEST) is not present in your .config file (since you moved your old config from older kernel to newer one). Thus, every new config option which is available in kernel, you need to set if you want it or not. If you don't want to use those new features, just in loop write n and enter. If you want to keep default value, just press enter until you check every new config option.